# I need to loop a working Google App Script, using JavaScript. (PDF Mail Merge)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've managed to get a nice PDF Mail Merge Google App Script working to my needs after a bit of tinkering. My problem now is, I would like the "Mail Merge PDF" function to run across every row in the spreadsheet, maybe stopping when it hits a blank row. I imagine there would be a more efficient way, using an array. At this point, I'm a bit stumped.

I've tried to document the code as best as possible to make it reusable. The script is working fine in its current state, although it's limited to processing a single row.

Regards
New_2_Code

```js
// Create Custom Scripts Menu in the Google Sheet this script resides in and where the data is housed.
function onOpen() {
    var menuEntries = [{
        name: "Long Service Award Generator",
        functionName: "PDFMailMerge"
    }];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.addMenu("Custom Scripts", menuEntries);
}

function PDFMailMerge() {

    // Enter the ID of the Google Docs Document you wish to use as a Template for your Document.
    var sleepINT = 1500
    var templateid = "1g0-ydpw_ZsKjcRZ_yKgaqHFFf56DmP4orA1t1MNFpPA"; // template file id
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.toast("10%: Template Sheet Aquired.");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 15).getValues();
    ss.toast("25%: Template data captured.");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

    // Make a copy of the Long Service Award template, then Fill up it up with the data from the Long Service Award Spreadsheet. 
    for (var i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy().getId();
        var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
        var body = doc.getActiveSection();
        body.replaceText("%Preferred_Name%", row[0]);
        body.replaceText("%Last_Name%", row[1]);
        body.replaceText("%Emp_No%", row[2]);
        body.replaceText("%EMAIL%", row[3]);
        body.replaceText("%Personnel_Sub_Area_Desc%", row[4]);
        body.replaceText("%Personnel_Sub_Area_Desc%", row[5]);
        doc.saveAndClose();
    }
    ss.toast("40%: Template data has been replaced.");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

    //Specifiy a Google Drive Folder by it's URL ID below.
    //Create a duplicate of the newly modified Template to the specified folder, then delete the originally modified Template from the specified folder.
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
    var newfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1x3uJOuXvKMeoZpWXV7g5nJ_tujMXymaO");
    var oldfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1x3uJOuXvKMeoZpWXV7g5nJ_tujMXymaO");
    newfolder.addFile(file);
    oldfolder.removeFile(file);
    ss.toast("60%: Template has been put in correct folder.");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);


    //Customizing the Template Title
    var usernamefordoctitle = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 1).getValues() // this is grabbing the customer name field (A2)
    var name = doc.getName();
    doc.setName('Template Name for ' + usernamefordoctitle);
    ss.toast("70%: named new Long Service Award");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

    //Set a Google Drive Folder's URL ID below, .PDF Files generated through this method will be stored in this folder.
    //Create a PDF File using the Modified Template created earlier in the script and name the resulting .PDF file according to the Template Title
    var pdffolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1x3uJOuXvKMeoZpWXV7g5nJ_tujMXymaO");
    var pdfFILE = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
    pdfFILE.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
    var theFolder = pdffolder;
    var theFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfFILE);
    theFolder.addFile(theFile);
    ss.toast("80%: PDF generated");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

    //Send an email to recepient (Email Values in Colmun D) - Attatch PDF File Created Earlier.
    var pdfEMAIL = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
    var message = "Hi " + usernamefordoctitle + "!, please kindly find your invoice attached.\nMany Thanks!\nMe";
    var emailAdd = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue()
    var emailTo = emailAdd; // add customer email here
    var subject = "Long Service Award for " + usernamefordoctitle;

    var attach = {
        fileName: 'Long Service Award for ' + usernamefordoctitle + '.pdf',
        content: pdfEMAIL,
        mimeType: 'application/pdf'
    };
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {
        attachments: [attach]
    });
    ss.toast("90%: " + usernamefordoctitle + "has been emailed.");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

    ss.toast("100%: Template for " + usernamefordoctitle + " has been created. Doc ID: " + docid);
    Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);
}
```

UPDATE:
I have tried to implement nested for loops. The I am not having much success at the moment. The script executes without error, however only the first line is processed. (Equal to the length of "sheet.getLastRow()".)

Apologies in advance for the poorly formatted code. I am burnt out and cannot edit it correctly.

Code is below:

```js
// Create Long Service Award Menu in Google Sheet this script resides in and where the data is housed.
function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Test", functionName: "PDFMailMerge"}];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.addMenu("Custom Scripts", menuEntries);
}

function PDFMailMerge() {

//Super Loop
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet2 = ss2.getActiveSheet();
for(var index2 = 1; index2 < sheet2.getLastRow(); index2++)
{
    var data2 = sheet2.getRange(index2,1,1,15).getValues();
    for (var i in data2) {
        var row = data2[i];
        //your code here
  
  
  // Enter the ID of the Google Docs Document you wish to use as a Template for your Document.
  var sleepINT = 1500
  var templateid = "1g0-ydpw_ZsKjcRZ_yKgaqHFFf56DmP4orA1t1MNFpPA"; // template file id
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.toast("10%: Template Sheet Aquired.");
  Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);
  
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,15).getValues();                                           
  ss.toast("25%: Template data captured."); 
  Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

if (index2 < sheet.getLastRow()){
for (var j = 0; j < sheet.getLastRow(); j++)
{var data = sheet.getRange(1+j,1,1,15).getValues();
j++}
}
else {
ss.toast("Error")
}

//var data needs to increment
// Make a copy of the Long Service Award template, then Fill up it up with the data from the Long Service Award Spreadsheet. 
for (var i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy().getId();
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
var body = doc.getActiveSection();
body.replaceText("%Preferred_Name%", row[0]);
body.replaceText("%Last_Name%", row[1]);
body.replaceText("%Emp_No%", row[2]);
body.replaceText("%%Personnel_Sub_Area%%", row[4]);
body.replaceText("%Personnel_Sub_Area_Desc%", row[5]);
doc.saveAndClose();
}
ss.toast("40%: Template data has been replaced.");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

//Specifiy a Google Drive Folder by it's URL ID below.
//Create a duplicate of the newly modified Template to the specified folder, then delete the originally modified Template from the specified folder.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
var newfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1x3uJOuXvKMeoZpWXV7g5nJ_tujMXymaO");
var oldfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1x3uJOuXvKMeoZpWXV7g5nJ_tujMXymaO");
newfolder.addFile(file);
oldfolder.removeFile(file);    
ss.toast("60%: Template has been put in correct folder.");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);


if (index2 < sheet.getLastRow()){
for (var p = 1; p < sheet.getLastRow(); p++)
{var usernamefordoctitle = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 1).getValues();
p++}
// Column in range in usernamefordoctitle must increment up   
//Customizing the Template Title
var usernamefordoctitle = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 1).getValues() // this is grabbing the customer name field (A2)
var name = doc.getName();
doc.setName('Template Name for ' + usernamefordoctitle);
ss.toast("70%: named new Long Service Award");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);
}
else {
var usernamefordoctitle = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 1).getValues() // this is grabbing the customer name field (A2)
var name = doc.getName();
doc.setName('Template Name for ' + usernamefordoctitle);
ss.toast("70%: named new Long Service Award");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);
}

//Does not need incrememnting - The value for usernamefordoctitle is used here which is incrememented
//Set a Google Drive Folder's URL ID below, .PDF Files generated through this method will be stored in this folder.
//Create a PDF File using the Modified Template created earlier in the script and name the resulting .PDF file according to the Template Title
var pdffolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1x3uJOuXvKMeoZpWXV7g5nJ_tujMXymaO");
var pdfFILE = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
pdfFILE.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
var theFolder = pdffolder;
var theFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfFILE);
theFolder.addFile(theFile);
ss.toast("80%: PDF generated");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

if (index2 < sheet.getLastRow()){
for (var k = 0; k < sheet.getLastRow(); k++)
{var data = sheet.getRange(1+k,1,1,15).getValues();
k++}
}
else {
ss.toast("Error")
}
//email add needs to be changed to get value and be incrememented
//Send an email to recepient (Email Values in Colmun D) - Attatch PDF File Created Earlier.
var pdfEMAIL = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
var message = "Hi " + usernamefordoctitle + "!, please kindly find your invoice attached.\nMany Thanks!\nMe";
var emailAdd = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue()
var emailTo = emailAdd; // add customer email here
var subject = "Long Service Award for " + usernamefordoctitle;
        
var attach = {fileName:'Long Service Award for ' + usernamefordoctitle + '.pdf',content:pdfEMAIL, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});
ss.toast("90%: " + usernamefordoctitle + "has been emailed.");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);  

ss.toast("100% Template for " + usernamefordoctitle + " has been created. Doc ID: "); 
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
for(var index = 1; index < sheet.getLastRow(); index++)
{
    var data = sheet.getRange(index,1,1,15).getValues();
    for (var i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Liora, the snippet of you you gave me seems to work well enough. It runs the script once per line which is what I was looking for. Problem now, it it still only processes the first line. I am thinking I can use a similar for loop as yours in sections where I need the script to read data from the next row. Will tinker with it, and once I have a working version I will post it here for everyone to make use of. (Thanks again for your help.)